# What does it mean to say "since the magnitude of actual momentum is smaller than uncertainty, the value cannot be defined"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

What does it mean to say "since the magnitude of actual momentum is smaller than uncertainty, the value cannot be defined"?

Original question:

> Uncertainty in the momentum of an electron is $ 2.6 \times 10 ^{-23}\, \mathrm{Kg m s}^{-1} $. Suppose the momentum is $ 1 \times 10^{-24}\, \mathrm{Kg m s}^{-1} $. Is there a problem defining ths value?

Answer: Since the magnitude of actual momentum is smaller than uncertainty, the value cannot be defined.

Can anyone please explain this?

Comment: Got it.  Good analogy.

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/319313/error-uncertainty-interval-goes-negative-while-the-value-is-known-to-be-positive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the possible error is larger than the value supposed for the momentum.

Which leaves you with the problem that you cannot define or measure the actual value at this time. If the measuring equipment can be improved for example, then the uncertainty could possibly be reduced allowing a value to be determined, but the question does not mention measuring equipment or changes.